# Utilizing VLookup in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am currently working on a spreadsheet and would like to utilize vlookup, but would prefer if it was through VBA.

I attached two screenshots of sheets, so you guys could visually see what i am trying to do.

Essentially I am trying to pull the "Priority" from sheet IW38 column K and place it on sheet "IW47" column R, but by using the order number as the matching info. The order numbers are in Column "E" in sheet IW47 and Column "A" in sheet IW47.

Below is the current macro I attempted to use:

```
Sub PriorityNUM()

'Variables----------------------------------------

'Defining WorkBook
Dim wb As Workbook

'Defining Sheets----------------------------------------------
'Working Asset Sheet
Dim IW47ws As Worksheet
'Sheet for Parts List Submission
Dim IW38ws As Worksheet

'Setting Worksheets
Set IW47ws = Sheets("IW47")
Set IW38ws = Sheets("IW38")

'Defigning Ranges within Worksheets----------------------------
Dim IW38rng As Range

'Setting Ranges within Submit Worksheets-------------------
Set IW38rng = IW38ws.Range("A:Z")

'Defining the Last Cell in Each Task Column----------------
Dim IW47last As Long

'Assigning Values to Last Row Variables
IW47last = IW47ws.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Updating Drawings Identified---------------------------------------------------
Dim PriorityCell As Range
Dim PriorityLookup As String

For Each PriorityCell In IW47ws.Range("R:R")
If IsEmpty(DICell.Offset(0, -13).Value) Then
Exit For
End If
On Error Resume Next
PriorityLookup = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PriorityCell.Offset(0, -13), IW38rng, 11, False)

If Err = 0 Then
PriorityCell.Value = PriorityLookup
Else
Err.Clear
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Next PriorityCell

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Juan

Comment: Just realized I can't post images yet. Sorry.

Comment: Point of failure is an important thing to share.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I am get a "424" Error code, But to be 100% honest I am not sure if I did it correctly to begin with. Appreciate the response!

Comment: And I think you need to use `PriorityCell.Offset(0, -13).Value` instead of `PriorityCell.Offset(0, -13)`

Comment: 424 after execution of what line?

Comment: I think its the first line. It does it as soon as I run it. I am using excel on a macbook, so I don't know if that might be an issue as well.

Comment: What is `DICell`? Regarding Mac...I'm pretty sure VBA is VBA.

Comment: DICell is the original name of one of the cells I use. I renamed it priority. I will change that. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: A mac should be able to evaluate everything here. I would recommend condensing your code - readability goes a long way in troubleshooting.

Comment: What line gives you an error? Step through the code, at what point do you get an error?

Comment: You need to start stepping through your code to reveal the actual failure point. Click within your code and hit `F8` then `F8` repeatedly until the program throws an error. You should type in `Option Explicit` at the top...this would reveal that DICell is not properly dimensioned. Also, compile your code to reveal issues before run-time.

Comment: agree with urdearboy completely...you need to structure your code for readability...e.g. indent the code within your conditional blocks and loops.

Comment: I wish I would have known about the Immediate window when I first started using VBA. You can check values and run commands/subs on the fly in there...Seriously, look into that.

Comment: Wow! thanks everyone it is working now. This is a great community on stackoverflow. I should have joined sooner. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that I was incorrect about `Offset` requiring `Value` after it. It's just like any other cell reference where `Value` is the default. I was thinking of something else.

Comment: And feel free to upvote some of these comments.

Comment: Yes! I know how to up vote the answers, but how do I upvote comments?

Comment: It only shows the flag option. Do you think its because I just joined the site today?

Comment: Yes, now that you mention that, yes...there is a threshold you have to cross before you can upvote. Please don't flag me! ;).

Comment: Hahaha that def won't happen.   Thanks again!!!

Comment: Hey quick question. My macro was working for a few days, but now it seems like it just keeps running or it freezes excel all together. Any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Readability

OP, your code can be restructured like below. I also used some short hand variables to make things easier. Your variable names would ideally be concise (easy to read and short to type). Readability goes a long way in troubleshooting.

Let me know once you have seen this so I can delete

```
Sub PNum()

Dim ws47 As Worksheet: Set ws47 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IW47")
Dim ws38 As Worksheet: Set ws38 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IW38")

Dim Arr As Range: Set Arr = ws38.Range("A:K")

Dim LR As Long, MyCell As Range, Priority As String

LR = ws47.Range("E" & ws47.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each MyCell In ws47.Range("R2:R" & LR)
    If IsEmpty(MyCell.Offset(-13)) Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
        Priority = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MyCell.Offset(, -13), Arr, 11, 0)

        If Err = 0 Then
            MyCell = Priority
        Else
            Err.Clear
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Just read your comment. With the help of the S.O community i was able to get mine to work, but i will also give this a shot. Thanks a lot.  I really appreciate you taking the time and help me. 
Juan